# How can I make an axios stream read + file write synchron?

Tags: node.js, axios, fs

I try get a file and rename it.

I get the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename './tmp.png' -> './tmp2.png'
```

The reason is createWriteStream is not finished if renameSync is called! File './tmp.png' not exist! How can I make the file reading synchron?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

let url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Friedrich_II._Schwertgroschen_1456_bis_1461%2C_Vorderseite%2C_CNG.PNG"

async function main (){
    await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        responseType: "stream",
    })
        .then(async (res) => {

            const writer = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp.png")
            await res.data.pipe( await writer )

            writer.on('finish', () => console.log("Finished"));
            writer.on('error', () => console.error("Error while dowloading image"));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}


main()

fs.renameSync("./tmp.png", "./tmp2.png", () => {
    console.log("\nFile Renamed!\n")
});


console.log("end program")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put the writer callback in a promise:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Friedrich_II._Schwertgroschen_1456_bis_1461%2C_Vorderseite%2C_CNG.PNG";

const writer = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp.png");

async function saveDownloadImage() {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        responseType: "stream",
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    response.data.pipe(writer)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('finished')
            resolve()
        })
        writer.on('error', () => {
            console.log('reject')
            reject()
        })
    })
};

async function test() {
    const asdf = await saveDownloadImage();

    fs.renameSync("./tmp.png", "./tmp2.png");
    console.log('after image save')
}

test();
console.log("end program");
```

Another way is to use synchronous functions of fs package fs.OpenSync, fs.WriteSync instead of fs.createWriteStream. But I don't know how this works and I haven't found any democode either.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `file rename` into the `.on('finish'...` event.
That event is fired once the write to file of the first image is completed and no additional data is written.

The code below was verified to produce the rename as wanted.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

let url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Friedrich_II._Schwertgroschen_1456_bis_1461%2C_Vorderseite%2C_CNG.PNG"

async function main() {
    await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        responseType: "stream",
    })
        .then(async (res) => {
            const writer = fs.createWriteStream("./tmp.png")
            await res.data.pipe(await writer)

            writer.on('finish', () =>{
                console.log("Finished");
            fs.renameSync("./tmp.png", "./tmp2.png", () => {
                console.log("\nFile Renamed!\n")
            });
            });
            writer.on('error', () => console.error("Error while dowloading image"));
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

main()
console.log("end program")
```

Comment: ** tangential **
If the `filename` is to follow some form of iterative scheme, use `template literals` and some form of name generator.

Comment: you can do this, but it's not "Separation of concerns"

Comment: An alternative approach would be await on the `get`, await on write of tmp.png (separate async func), await on write of `fileRename` (separate async func)

Comment: The above is separating all concerns: fetch, write temp, rename temp. All separate funcs. catch on each of those funcs since they are async, try catch around all 3 func calls.